# Swift @functionBuilder doesn't recognize variadic elements

Tags: ios, swift, function-builder

I'm using a function builder in my project and am having problems implementing `buildIf`. Here's the builder:

```
@_functionBuilder
class TableSectionBuilder {
    static func buildBlock(_ children: TableGroup...) -> [TableGroup] {
        children
    }

    static func buildBlock(_ children: [TableGroup]...) -> [TableGroup] {
        children.flatMap { $0 }
    }

    static func buildExpression(_ child: TableGroup) -> [TableGroup] {
        [child]
    }

    static func buildIf(_ children: [TableGroup]?) -> [TableGroup] {
      return children ?? []
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how I'd like to use it (note: `Text` is a custom object, similar to `SwiftUI`'s `Text`)

```
func test() {
    Self.section(identifier: "") {
        Text("")
        Text("")
        if true {
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile, though this compiles:

```
func test() {
    Self.section(identifier: "") {
        [Text(""),
        Text("")]
        if true {
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

It looks to me that the function builder cannot properly map from an array to a variadic list of items. Also, removing the `if` in the first example makes it compile.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limit of Swift today. It is inherently why SwiftUI views are limited to 10 right now, and you see methods like `combineLatest3` and `combineLatest4` in the Combine framework.

[According to the swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/function-builders-implementation-progress/32981), variadic function builders is something being worked on and may be included in Swift 6.